# I'm having trouble unbinding windows key shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I am currently playing a game that requires that i press `ESC`+`CTRL` at the same time, but this opens a windows menu. If i unbind it by using something like `^Esc::return` in AHK it stops me from pressing `ESC`+`CTRL` in game. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

> *The CTRL+ESC keyboard shortcut is hard coded by the shell application,*
>   *and it's not configurable.*

**But** if all you want is to play a game then you can :

1- Run your game first.

1- Open up **Resource Monitor**. (Windows+R) then type (resmon).

2- Go-to **CPU** tap .

3- Right-click **explorer.exe** then choose **suspend process** option.

Now you can press ctrl+esc all day and the start menu will not open up, while any running application including your game will still receive the keypress and work fine.

and when done playing :

In **Resource Monitor** Right-click **explorer.exe** then choose **resume process** option and everything will go back to normal.